# C# Global Variables for Instances of a class

Tags: c#

I understand that questions about Global Variables in C# has been asked so many times, but if possible would anyone be able to explain how to use an instance of one class that's being created in one method, but also being needed in another method as I have to rely on one instance and not to create multiple instances. Other questions online haven't been of help of what I seen.

My code below:

```
    public void loadCreateAccountCtr()
    {
        // Create Controller
        CreateAccountController ctr = new CreateAccountController();
        // Start Controller
        ctr.start();
        // Session is active
    }

    public void checkCredentials(string appNum)
    {
        CreateAccountController ctr = new CreateAccountController();
        ctr.create();

    }
```

I'm creating an instance of the CreateAccountController 'ctr' so I can access the methods in the controller, when I am going to send data to another part of the system I need to call another method. How would I use the previous instance without creating a new instance (As seen in checkCredentials(...)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

read about variable scopes in C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

```
private CreateAccountController ctr;
public void loadCreateAccountCtr()
{
    // Create Controller
    ctr = new CreateAccountController();
    // Start Controller
    ctr.start();
    // Session is active
}

public void checkCredentials(string appNum)
{
    if (ctr != null)
    {
        ctr.create();
    }
    else
    {
        //handle this case here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm, I feel a bit stupid now that it was something simple I had not thought of. (I'll mark it as correct asap)

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is the Singleton Design Pattern. Read about it and see examples [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

However ahmelsayed's answer solves your problem perfectly in this situation, if later you will have to access the same class from other classes in your system, implementing your `CreateAccountController` as Singleton would solve the problem globally.
You can get back to this later. Good luck!

Comment: You are correct, sadly I haven't touched C# in several months, I seen it from looking online about my question, but most answers just over complicated the question that was being asked.

Comment: You are right. Some examples are over complicating it. In your case you can keep it simple.